# How to dismiss splitView in windows 10 universal app?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, splitview

I have a login page from which I go to another page with a splitview menu. In this menu there is an option for log out from the app. In this case, I want to go to the login page again, but I don't know how to charge that page in the full page (only charge the page in the content frame but the split view is still there). How can I clear/dismiss it?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you put more xaml code of the page with splitview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your implementation but this should work on any page:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(YourLoginPageType));
```

or this should work everywhere

```
Frame rootFrame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(YourLoginPageType));
```